# Display SKSpriteNode in a specific duration

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my `GameOverScene` I have a `SKSpriteNode` that I would like to appear with in a specific duration. So that when the scene `GameOverScene` loads the `SKSpriteNode` with the texture "Play Again" needs 2 seconds to appear.

```
playButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: playAgainTex)
    playButton.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.45, self.frame.size.height * 0.33)
    self.addChild(playButton)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: playAgainTex)
    playButton.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.45, self.frame.size.height * 0.33)

    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)
    let add = SKAction.runBlock { self.addChild(playButton) }
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, add])
    self.runAction(sequence)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You want to run an animation after the button has appeared?

Comment: I want the button to appear as an animation, so that it looks more fluid.